# Artists similar to French artist Paradis

Tags: electronic-music, similar-artists

Anyone know where to find more of this genre? The french element is absolutely narcotic: [Paradis - Hémisphère](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OkN1m4AgIY)

I tried looking into lounge/electronic/indie/house, but couldn't find any comparables. Paradis seem to be a unique of its own?

Answer (score 2):

I have been a long time fan of the band Stereolab https://www.discogs.com/artist/388-Stereolab 
Although this group is from London, there is an overwhelming French influence due to the French born singer Lætitia Sadier. This band definitely falls into the lounge/electronic genre.